# Calculate splitter distance on different screen resolutions

Tags: c#, resolution, splitter

I have a form which contains the following:

1. Splitter Control
2. Datagridview in first panel
3. Dynamically created controls on second panel

What I am doing, accoring to the number of controls required, I adjust the splitter distance according to the number of controls so that all controls are visible and blank space reduce automatically. On my system which has screen resolution 1920x1080, its working fine but when I tried to use it on different resolutions, the splitter distance is not correctly set and controls are not properly visible.
Now I want to calculate the splitter distance based on user screen resolution.

Can anybody guide me how to achieve this?

Comment: the controls position are fixed?

Comment: Control are being placed in the rows..